# Azure Hybrid Connection - GatewayTimeout

Tags: azure, connection, hybrid

I've been trying to get `Azure Hybrid Connection` to works for a long time now but I always get a GatewayTimeout exception:

```
{"error":{"code":"GatewayTimeout","message":"The request was routed to the listener but the listener did not respond in the required time. }}
```

I'm trying to expose a web api running locally using VS (I've tried both kestrel and iis express)

I suspect it's got something to do with the endpoint host but I've tried everything I can think of:

- **localhost**
- **computer name**
- **domain** set in etc/hosts
- **google.com**

Comment: You may get the reference from [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/using-azure-app-services-with-hybrid-connections/) Which step do you get this error?

Comment: I can telnet the servicebus endpoint, and if I call using no Authentication header or with a wrong sas token I get an "TokenMissingOrInvalid" exception. I therefor assume the call gets all the way to the hybrid connector, but it then fails to make the local call to the web service.